# Unable to write stream using Databricks Autoloader

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I can currently read and write batch jobs However when I try to run the write stream, it says "Running Command" and it just keeps running without the output. I have the checkpoint folder being created, but I can't see my delta files. There is no _delta_log folder being created. I'm not sure what the issue is and my code is as follows:

```
cloudFilesOption = {
    "cloudFiles.format": "csv",
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications": "true", # Use file notifications for efficient discovery
    "cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles": "true", # Process existing files in addition to new ones
    "cloudFiles.connectionString": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="stockseval-con-string", key="stockseval-con-string"),
    "cloudFiles.resourceGroup": "stocks",
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="subscription-id", key="subscription-id"),
    "cloudFiles.tenantId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="tenant-id", key="tenant-id"),
    "cloudFiles.clientId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="clientid", key="clientid"),
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "adls-db", key = "client-secret"),
    "cloudFiles.maxFilesPerTrigger": "100", # Number of files to process per micro-batch
    "cloudFiles.schemaLocation" : "abfss://financialdatabronze@stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    "cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode" : "addNewColumns"
}

landing_loc = "/mnt/financialdatalandingzone/balancesheet/annualreports/"


df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").options(**cloudFilesOption).option("Header" ,True).load(landing_loc)
 
bronze_layer = "/mnt/financialdatabronze/balancesheet/annualreports/"
df.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").trigger(once= True).queryName("Autoloader").option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/financialdatabronze/balancesheet/annualreports_checkpoint/").start(bronze_layer).awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code mostly looks correct, you need to troubleshoot the issue like:

1. check permissions of "read location" and "write location"
2. check the schemaLocation path is right
3. check and update spark and delta lake version

the best way is to find the logs or error report because without them it tough to find the root cause.